# IBOutlet properties from Swift framework are missing from Objective-C app

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, swift

I have a framework I've written in Swift that contains a class that extends `UIView` and that has an `IBOutlet` property.

The class is visible from my Objective-C app, but Interface Builder won't see the IBOutlet. Here's the code:

```
@objc protocol MyFrameworkDelegate {
    // My delegate methods here
    ...
}

@objc class MyFrameworkClass: UIView {

    @objc @IBOutlet var delegate:MyFrameworkDelegate?
    // The rest of my class here
    ...
}
```

I set my view's class to `MyFrameworkClass` in my storyboard, but the `delegate` outlet isn't showing.

I tried with and without the `@objc` modifier, no luck. When I inspect my class from Objective-C, the property comes up without the `IBOutlet`.

Anyone else came across something like that?

**EDIT**

Here's the code generated by Xcode for the Swift -> Objective-C conversion:

```
@protocol MyFrameworkDelegate;

SWIFT_CLASS("_Nc9a0xD6MyFrameworkClass")
@interface MyFrameworkClass : UIView
@property (nonatomic) id <MyFrameworkDelegate> delegate;
...
```

Also, here's the error message I get when I try to run the app:

```
2014-06-22 21:41:59.095 MyApp Test[75211:17812266] Unknown class MyFrameworkClass in Interface Builder file.
2014-06-22 21:41:59.099 MyApp Test[75211:17812266] -[UIView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcf5d650
2014-06-22 21:41:59.101 MyApp Test[75211:17812266] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcf5d650'
```

**EDIT**

Here's a screenshot of my storyboard:

[image]

Comment: Also, I might add, if I implement the framework in Objective-C, it works correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your module is `None`, you should select it to your corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

> `reason: '-[UIView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector`

This makes it look like the object in question is an instance of `UIView`, not `MyFrameworkClass`. Check the type of the object in IB.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the word delegate itself is triggering some kind of underlying bug/mechanism/leaky abstraction.

How about calling it myFrameworkDelegate?

I am also wondering if dragging from IB shouldn't always give the best results by itself but I need to fire up Xcode 6 and test manually first to see what happens. New technology :)

Comment: Objective-C doesn't have a `delegate` keyword. It's simply a convention.

Comment: Tried to repro for you, Xcode just dies when I drag and drop.

Comment: Yeah, it's not quite there yet.

Comment: Tried beta 2, still crashes. I'll abandon the UI connecting. 

"Unknown class MyFrameworkClass in Interface Builder file."

 I think this might just be a bug in the automatic import that Swift has.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
@objc @IBOutlet var delegate:MyFrameworkDelegate?
```

use

```
@IBOutlet var delegate:AnyObject?
```

than you'll be able to link your class to this property.